# How does the baseclass call the Session_End method from Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect the user to a login page once their session has expired. I created a base page which will be inherited by each aspx code behind file.

What i would really like to know is how can you set the basepage method to automatically perform the redirect once the Session_End() method has been called on session timeout?

I have searched for over an hour on Google for a solution to this but still have come up short.

I have never used the global.asax page before and it is my first time creating a basepage so any advice or explanations would be great thanks

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using ? form based ?

Comment: @Kek No im using windows authentication

Comment: @user2500842 I thought Windows Authentication defaults to the Windows logged in user and a custom login page is not required. Is this not the case?

Comment: @ZaidMasud Yes but this is for login only, when the session timesout i have to find a way to repeat this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between myself and a work colleague we have managed to resolve this question.

The solution is as follows:

Within my application i used a session variable to store the user name.

Once the session timed out then of course the user name session variable would be cleared from memory. This was the trigger i needed to force the application to return to the index page.

**Solution**

1st step:

//in the base class enter the following code

```
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["username"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/SessionTimeout.aspx");
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

2nd step:

For each aspx code behind file i.e. the aspx.cs file for web form, instead of inheriting from the default (System.web.UI.Page) inherit from the base page:

```
   public partial class SessionTimeout : BasePage
    {
    }
```

final step:

set the sessionState attributes

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, because when the Session_End gets fired, the user is inactive for a long time and probably the connection has been closed already.

What you need to do is run some sort of javascript timer in all pages, which would redirect the user when it has expired.

Kind regards,

Edwin.

Answer (score 2):

Your Question: `how can you set the basepage method to automatically perform the redirect once the Session_End() method has been called on session timeout`

You can  call your Base page method from global.asax file. This method you will call in the Session_End() [ which is called when session expires or ends ]. Inside this basePage method put your custom logic for redirection.

However, you should agree that If you need to call a PAGE method from outside, that's surely a bad design to an extent.

```
Base.aspx:

public class BasePage : Page
{

    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Global.asax

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  BasePage.MyMethod();

}
```

Refer this post for more details: http://forums.asp.net/t/1426012.aspx/1

Comment: Yes i agree that it may be a bad design but as its my first time dealing with these issues im sure i will know for future. thanks for your post

Answer (score 1):

Well, Authentication is based on a cookie (at least form authentication, I am not sure for windows based).
You could simply remove this cookie when you receive an authenticated request with no associated session. On login, you create the session.

You could delete auth cokie with

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```